# Order by a temporary column computed using case when

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria, criteria-api

I have 2 entities Book and BookProperty in a one-to-many relationship. I need to retrieve books sorted by upload_date, english language books coming first using JPA Criteria with pagination and stuff (JPQL/native sql is not an option).

This is what the native query for this operation would look like (postgres):

```
select distinct 
    b.book_id, 
    b.name, b.author, ... , 
    b.upload_date, 
    case when p.property_name='language' and lower(p.property_value)='english' 
         then 0 else 1 end as book_language, 
from books b 
left outer join book_properties p 
on b.book_id=p.book_id 
order by book_language asc, b.upload_date desc;
```

The problem is that I can't get the 'case' part to be selected via criteria API and sort by it. I know that it is possible via a multiselect and a tuple but I would like to avoid that, because really I do not need this column in the application. I would like to just retrieve sorted Book objects and not tuples of (Book, Integer).

I tried to move the case part into the order by and managed to compute the query via JPA Criteria, but in that case setDistinct(true) resulted in an error, because all columns in order by must be part of distinct. So moving the case part to order doesn't look like an option.

Please help me implement this query using JPA Criteria, preferably without using tuples or wrapper objects, but that will do as well if there are no other options.

Comment: There's no need to add tags to your title, there's a tag system for that. Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190 for the general discussion.

Comment: I can't help, but your query would be _much_ easier if the property `language` were a property of `book` class...